# Could not download Silverlight application. Does not appear to be MIME type issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a problem with a Silverlight control inside an ASP.NET MVC3 page.  The silverlight control works on one of my views but on another page I get the following error:

```
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings
```

Everything that I've read says that it's a MIME type error, but the type is registered and the control works on another page.  The test pages work as well.  I'm kind of stuck.  Has anyone seen this or have other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Load up fiddler and see whats going on in the request. That's the first step and may make it obvious.

Comment: That definitely helped.  One of the calls is getting my localization string appended to it and the other isn't.  One calls has the URL: `http://localhost/myapp/en/ClientBin/silverlight.xap
` while the other, which works, is less the "en".  The both have the same path which is odd.  If I add an extra ../ to the source param on the silverlight call it works, but I'm not sure why the other works without that.

Comment: when the call that appends it calls, is there a different culture being set by that time?